# Rails: render value without view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i've a problem 
i'm trying to make an action method like this

```
 def webm
    @url = Video.find(params[:id]).avatar.url(:webm_sd)
  end
```

and i just want to return the @url value without using view .. it will return string url i need it to be rendered where ever the method get called

it gives me error

> Missing template api/v1/videos/webm, application/webm with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

and even if i add some views in videos folder it still gives me the same error!

what should i do?

Comment: `use return @url` next is  `render :nothing => true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proper renderer

```
render json: @url
```

or to render just string

```
render text: @url
```